# How to reuse ubuntu (installed on USB HDD) on another computer?

Tags: external-hdd

I have installed Ubuntu on the USB HDD and successfully used it on my old notebook(acer). After purchasing the new computer(asus), i can't load my Ubuntu. Following the grub load screen i got black screen. Any way, i successfully launched Ubuntu in recovery mode without wireless drivers, but it doesn't look like a solution. Can anyone help me in my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a video issue on the new PC.  Boot the USB, then switch to one of the virtual terminals with ctrl alt Fn1 (or function keys 2 through 6 should work too). Look at the modules with:

```
lsmod | sort
```

and see what proprietary video drivers you are using, and remove them with:

```
sudo apt-get purge <the proprietary video driver>
```

See if rebooting gets you to a working video, maybe add "nomodeset" to the grub command that starts with "linux"
Add any new proprietary video (wireless gets the same treatment) drivers.

---

With the same video chips, and it working in recovery mode, may be an X problem.  Look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log (or others with higher numbers) for any errors. Does the guest session work?  If so, maybe some config problem down in your .config directory.

Comment: But on the my old computer and on the new has Intel Graphics. In the theory it should work correctly. I tried to update system via apt-get dist-upgrade but it does not take any effect
I tried to make lsmod and i saw video - i915, i915_bdw, asus_wmi. Should i purge video driver if it work correctly in recovery mode?